# How is it possible for a C struct to reference itself?

Tags: c, gcc

How does a C compiler (I'm using GCC) know what to do with the following?

```
struct node
{
    int x;
    struct node* next;
};
```

More precisely, if `node` has yet to be completely defined yet (we have not reached the closing curly brace), then how does the compiler know how big a struct ought to be?

While I realize that "pointing to" only requires an address,  incrementing pointers does require the size of the data it points to.

Comment: The pointer increments are handled only after the type(s) have been determined completely. Otherwise you will get errors mentioning 'incomplete types'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size of the `struct` is not important, as a pointer to the `struct` is being stored, not the `struct` itself.

In terms of incrementing pointers to `struct`; that is done outside of the `struct` definition, so again, is not important.